# Глюк с кодировкой в PHP jQuery

Tags: php, кодировка

Всем привет!

Суть проблемы следующая. Есть скрипт, который с помощью метода `jQuery.post()` отправляет ранее собранные данные формы на php скрипт. Вот js скрипт:

```
jQuery.post(
url = '/wp-content/themes/panorama/query.php', data = dataForm, function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

А вот тот самый php скрипт (в моём случае query.php). query.php - просто отсылает на почту письмо с данными из формы, которые были переданы `jQuery.post()`. Вот код query.php

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
} else {
    echo "error name";
}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
} else {
    echo "error email";
}
if (isset($_POST['subject'])) {
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
} else {
    echo "error subject";
}
if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
    $message = $_POST['message'];
} else {
    echo "error message";
}

$to         = "maler1988@yandex.ru";
$message    = $message . "<br/> отправитель: " . $name . " - " . $email . "";
$resultSend = mail($to, $subject, $message);

$success = "Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено!";
$defeat  = "Ошибка отправки сообщения";

$success = iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $success);
$defeat  = iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $defeat);

if ($resultSend == TRUE) {
    echo $success;
} else {
    echo $defeat;
}
```

Всё работает, письмо отсылается и т.п., но ответ о скрипте php приходит в непонятной кодировке и функция `alert(data);` выдаёт кракозябры. Не пойму, почему `iconv()` не помогает.

Посоветуйте, что делать? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В какой кодировке сам файл php?

Вот это можно заменить

```
$resultSend = mail($to, $subject, $message);

$success = "Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено!";
$defeat  = "Ошибка отправки сообщения";

$success = iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $success);
$defeat  = iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $defeat);

if ($resultSend == TRUE) {
    echo $success;
} else {
    echo $defeat;
}
```

на

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $message))
    echo iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', "Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено!");
else
    echo iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', "Ошибка отправки сообщения");
```

Покороче будет.

А то что кривые буквы - это кодировка. Скорее всего, везде она разная.

На странице может быть не UTF-8, а windows-1251, тогда иконв вернет бред, так же и на серверной стороне, если файл в utf-8, а ты его **iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8'** тоже будет бред.

Решение одно правильно сделать везде кодировку!

Comment: Спасибо большое! у меня оказывается был файл в кодировке UTF-8 (без BOM) , я его сменил на праильный а iconv() забыл убрать. вот мне и бред приходил!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте PHP-функцию [iconv()](http://www.php.su/functions/?iconv) или используйте функции из более-менее известного расширения MB_STRING. m[b_internal_encoding()](http://www.php.su/functions/?mb_internal_encoding), к примеру.

Кстати, вот этот кусочек кода:

```
   if(isset($_POST['name'])){$name = $_POST['name'];} else {echo "error name";}
   if(isset($_POST['email'])){$email = $_POST['email'];} else {echo "error email";}
   if(isset($_POST['subject'])){$subject = $_POST['subject'];} else {echo "error  
   subject";}
   if(isset($_POST['message'])){$message = $_POST['message'];} else {echo "error 
   message";}
```

просто ужасен! На него больно смотреть! Здесь ведь нет абсолютно никакой фильтрации введенных данных. А более-менее сообразительные юзеры поймут, что к чему и воспользуются этой дыркой...

Используйте здесь хотя бы `strip_tags` что ли)

Comment: т.е. фактически мне могут через форму послать какой-нибудь php код? Что-то вроде sql иньекции сделать только через форму? а какие ещё меры защиты посоветуете? Заранее спасибо!